# How can I set up shell tab-completion to toggle through alternatives?

Tags: linux, shell, tab-completion

When I type, e.g. "cd bu[tab]", and there is more than one option, (say build/ and builds/), the terminal usually shows a list of all possible options (after pressing [tab] twice). I want to set it up such that each [tab] press will cycle through the alternatives instead of showing a list of them:

$ cd bu[tab] -> $ cd build/ -> [tab] -> $ cd builds/ -> [tab] -> $ cd build/ etc.

I hope it is clear what I mean? :) mIRC has the same feature for nickname and channel completion, for instance.

Also, please tell me this is possible without writing my own completion script.

edit: I'm using the standard terminal on Ubuntu.

Comment: the standard terminal. didn't know this makes a difference.

Comment: Follow the link I added in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using `zsh`: The default zsh shell in grml behaves the way you mention (If I remember correctly). You can have a look at the configuration [here](http://grml.org/zsh/)

Edit:
For Ubuntu, see the accepted answer here: [Terminal autocomplete: cycle through suggestions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/terminal-autocomplete-cycle-through-suggestions)